# How do I input data from a CSV file into my code?

Tags: java, csv, input, load, java.util.scanner

I have a CSV file that is like:

- Orbit,a,e,i
- LEO,7168000,0,90
- MEO,20200000,0,54

What I want is that using scanner, I will be able to choose one of the two orbits I have in the CSV file. Let's say for example, using scanner if I put 1 in the console, it chooses the row of the CSV file: LEO,7168000,0,90 and if I put 2 the line: MEO,20200000,0,54.

After that from the row chosen it saves each parameter in a variable skipping the name (LEO,MEO). For example if I choose LEO orbit, it saves the variables like:

- double a = 7168000;
- double e = 0;
- double i = 90;

So in the end I can use those parameters in my program. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: If you are reading csv then I suggest using a csvReader

Comment: And how would it be coded? I am sorry but I am quite new using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Csv file is a plain text file and separates with `,` character for each cell and `\n` for each row.

The easy way, you only need using FileInputStream to read and split `\n` and `,` character for using.

```
File file = new File("file.csv");
FileInputStream fis = null;
String dataStr = "";
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    int content;
    while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
        dataStr += (char) content;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// convert to array rows string
String[] dataRows = dataStr.split("\n");

// loop rows to get cells string
for (int i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
    String[] dataCells = rowData[i].split(",");
    //do what ever you want with dataCells
}
```

Thanks for read.

Comment: Not so fast. Sepatator may be "," tab ";" or something else. Strings may be contains sepatators and must be escaped, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I do the scanner part to for example from the dataCells choose only one of the options because if I print dataCells[1] I get:
a
7168000
20200000
 And I only want to get one of the values.

Comment: And also the dataCells are String and I want each value as double as I will use it later on the code as parameter.

Comment: @Raúl you can use Double Array to save data for easy get data like a matrix of string ```String[][]```, And if you need to use data with ```double``` type, you can use method ```Double.parseDouble(string)```.

Comment: data with ```double``` type, you can use method ```Double.parseDouble(string)```.
another way, you create the class that defines all attribute you need ```Orbit,a,e,i```. Then define the list of the class defined and set it for each value of ```dataCells``` after split.

Comment: @CrutchMaster: thanks for your reply but I think this way is easy to understand for a beginner like me.